# Número de casos em um intervalo de idade (problemas quanto a alocação)

Tags: c, alocação

O usuário fornecerá várias (primeiro número dado) entradas triplas com o primeiro número sendo 0, o segundo número sendo o número de casos de doenças em uma idade determinada (terceiro número) OU o primeiro número sendo 1, o segundo e o terceiro números sendo os extremos de um intervalo de idade. Eu tenho que vincular "número de casos" com "idade" e poder editar esse número de casos, tem a possibilidade de receber mais casos para uma idade já citada anteriormente (primeiro número: 0). Além disso, ele fornecerá os números X e Y, de modo que eu tenho que imprimir o número de casos relacionados às idades entre X e Y (primeiro número: 1). A linguagem que estou usando é C.

Eu tentei esse código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int l[3], *list, n = 5;

void add(int X, int Y){
    while (Y < n){
        n = n * 2;
        list = realloc(list, n * sizeof(int));
    }
    list[Y] += X;
}

void consult(int X, int Y){
    int print = 0;
    for (int k = X; k <= Y; ++k){
        print += list[k];
    }
    printf("%d\n", print);
}

int main() {
    int P;
    scanf("%d", &P);
    list = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < P; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            scanf("%d", &l[j]);
        }
        if (l[0] == 0){
            add(l[1],l[2]);
        } else {
            consult(l[1],l[2]);
        }
    }
    free(list);
    return 0;
}
```

No exemplo:

```
20
0 194 9
1 7 41
0 102 38
1 30 43
0 22 49
1 34 56
1 15 20
1 34 57
1 34 51
0 128 39
0 97 57
0 114 25
0 10 82
0 127 35
1 66 164
0 60 85
0 155 48
1 60 186
1 10 384
0 166 950
```

ele está rodando corretamente. Porém no exemplo:

```
40
0 151 25
0 5 3
0 99 1
0 109 14
0 115 15
0 110 1
0 191 2
0 94 9
1 11 13
1 25 31
1 1 33
1 14 26
0 49 31
1 28 33
1 18 34
1 16 23
1 28 38
1 13 26
1 2 5
1 17 29
0 132 8
1 21 24
0 137 0
1 0 13
1 8 26
1 12 20
0 22 63
1 5 8
1 24 70
1 51 61
1 36 40
0 164 42
1 55 70
0 134 112
0 71 105
0 101 7
0 17 67
1 56 252
0 172 363
0 18 188
```

está dizendo "tamanho máximo da pilha ou da memória excedida, ou talvez apontador inválido (código 139)".

Como posso corrigir esse erro?

Observação: é uma obrigação iniciar o vetor com o tamanho 5 e, se o tamanho não for suficiente, tem que ir duplicando a capacidade de memória anterior até que o tamanho seja suficiente.

Comment: Atenção para o fato de quando você utiliza a função `realloc` todos os bytes que excedem o tamanho anterior tem valor indeterminado. Isto é um comportamento diferente da função `calloc` que zera a área alocada.

Comment: @anonimo Mas substituir a função ```realloc``` pela ```calloc``` não mudou em nada.

Comment: Eu não falei para substituir. Como você não atribui um valor inicial à área alocada o que excede a alocação anterior conterá lixo de memória, mas você pressupõe que contenha zero. Outra coisa é que na função `consult` você não verifica se Y está dentro da área alocada, considera que está o que pode não ser verdade.